# how to get two separate value from NSString Xcode

Tags: ios, nsstring

```
NSString *mystring = @"123 This is testing message";
```

Above string, I need to get two separate string just like follow.

```
NSString *one = @"123";
NSString *Two = @"This is testing message";
```

Is there any fast way to retrieve two separate string from `mystring`?

Comment: is there any specific that first will come only numbers?

Comment: What is your split criterion? Length, content, some token...

Comment: numeric length is fixed or not?

Comment: it would be easy if you put some separator between number and your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use this**

```
  - (NSString *)extractNumberFromText:(NSString *)text
  {
    NSCharacterSet *nonDigitCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    return [[text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigitCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
  }
```

For calling

```
NSString * str = @"123 This is testing message";
NSString *number = [self extractNumberFromText:str];
NSString *text = [str substringFromIndex:number.length+1];
```